# how can i hide out of stock product in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i need to hide  out of stock products from newest or latest products and best selling or top selling products
i already  do this for related products with this code

```
function hide_out_of_stock_option( $option ){
    return 'yes';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_template_part', function( $template_name ) {
    if( $template_name !== "single-product/related.php" ) {
        return;
    }
    add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items', 'hide_out_of_stock_option' );
} );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_template_part', function( $template_name ) {
    if( $template_name !== "single-product/related.php" ) {
        return;
    }
    remove_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items', 'hide_out_of_stock_option' );
} );
```

how can i do this for newest and best selling ?

Comment: Are you using the widget, or what?

Comment: nothing used just woocommerce

Comment: What do you mean "newest category"

Comment: i mean latest products and best selling products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pre_get_posts` action hook. to hide out-of-stock products.

`is_product_category()` - Returns true when viewing a product category archive.

`is_product_category( 'shirts' )` - When the product category page for the ‘shirts’ category is being displayed.

`is_product_category( array( 'shirts', 'games' ) )` - When the product category page for the ‘shirts’ or ‘games’ category is being displayed.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function hide_outofstock_products( $q ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_product_category('your category slug') ) {

    $q->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
        'key'     => '_stock_status',
        'value'   => 'outofstock',
        'compare' => 'NOT IN'
    )));

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_outofstock_products' );

}
```

Check more [Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: in this solution i think you hide all out of stock products from site but i need to hide from newest category and top selling

Comment: can you tell me what is the slug of top selling or best selling products and latest products